# Is $\{(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2 -\{(1,0)\} : x_1>-\frac{1}{2}\}$ homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{R}^2-\{(0,0)\}$?

Tags: homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

Is $\{(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2 -\{(1,0)\} : x_1>-\frac{1}{2}\}$ homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{R}^2-\{(0,0)\}$?

Actually I am trying to find the cohomology of $\mathbb{R}^2 -\{(1,0)\}$ by Mayer-Vietoris sequence and I wanted to split $\mathbb{R}^2 -\{(1,0)\}$ into $U = \{(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2 -\{(1,0)\} : x_1>-\frac{1}{2}\}$ and $V = \{(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2 -\{(1,0)\} : x_1<\frac{1}{2}\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only are they homotopy equivalent, they are actually homeomorphic. I'll give you some hints:

- Hint 1 : $\Bbb R^2$ and $X = \{(x_1, x_2) \in \Bbb R^2: x_1 > -\frac{1}{2} \}$ are homeomorphic.

Let $f : X \to \Bbb R^2$ be such a homeomorphism.

- Hint 2 : Let $g : \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ be the translation by $- f(1,0)$. Then, $(g|_{\Bbb R^2 - f(1, 0)}) \circ (f|_{X - (1, 0)})$ is the required homeomorphism.

Comment: Thank you! That was really helpful. I think I have found it with $f: X-\{(1,0)\} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$, $f(x_1,x_2)=(\log(\frac{2}{3}x_1+\frac{1}{3}), x_2)$ and $f^{-1}(x_1,x_2)=(\frac{3}{2}e^{x_1}-\frac{1}{2}, x_2)$.